# Zend Lucene index

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hello I am trying to build Lucene index. I have problem building index interrupt on server, on localhost works. I found somewhere maybe it's a problem because large number of data I cant figure why. On server I change max_execution time, and time_limit. I am calling this method

```
static public function indexSearchJedinice($params = null)      
{       
    $debug_file_path = 'c:/wamp/www/linkdl/debug/element.txt';
    $debug_file = fopen($debug_file_path, 'w');
    fwrite($debug_file, 'uso' ."\n");
        Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::setDefaultEncoding('utf-8');
    // Create index.  Will delete any existing index.
    $index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open('c:/wamp/www/linkdl/lucene/jedinice/');

    $sql = "
            SELECT DISTINCT KNJ.ID, KNJ.Naziv, KNJ.Opis, KNJ.UID
            FROM Kurs as K 
            LEFT JOIN KursPodaci as KP on K.ID = KP.IDKurs
            INNER JOIN KursPripadaGrupi as KPG ON K.ID = KPG.IDKurs
            INNER JOIN PodGrupa ON PodGrupa.ID = KPG.IDPodgrupa
            INNER JOIN KursSadrziNastavneModule ON KursSadrziNastavneModule.IDKurs = K.ID
            INNER JOIN KursModulSadrziJedinicu on KursModulSadrziJedinicu.IDKursNastavniModul = KursSadrziNastavneModule.IDKursNastavniModul
            INNER JOIN KursNastavnaJedinica as KNJ ON KNJ.ID = KursModulSadrziJedinicu.IDKursNastavnaJedinica

            WHERE K.ProdajniStatus IN (0,1) 
            AND KPG.IDCenovnikTip = 2 
            AND KNJ.JeZaPrikazivanje = 0
            ";



    //fwrite($debug_file, $sql ."\n");
    if ($jedinice =  Db::getResult($sql))
    {
        foreach ($jedinice as $jedinica)
        {
            //fwrite($debug_file, $jedinica['Naziv'] ."\n");
            $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('ID', $jedinica['ID']));
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('Naziv', $jedinica['Naziv'], 'utf-8'));
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('Opis', $jedinica['Opis'], 'utf-8'));
            //$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('Opis', '', 'utf-8'));
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('UID', $jedinica['UID']));
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('Type', 'jedinica'));

            $kratki_tekst = str_replace('&nbsp;', '',  str_replace('U izradi', '', strip_tags($jedinica['Opis'])));
            $kratki_tekst = create_short_text($kratki_tekst, 475);

            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('KratkiOpis', $kratki_tekst, 'utf-8'));

            $index->addDocument($doc);

            /**
             * Optimizacija indeksiranja
            */
            unset($doc);


        }
    }
    fwrite($debug_file, 'Optimizacija pocinje' ."\n");
    $index->commit();
    $index->optimize();
    fwrite($debug_file, 'Optimizacija zabrsena' ."\n");
    return true;
}
```

Can someone help me to understand diffrence between open/and create. 
And this options UnIndexed, UnStored,Text

Answer (score 0):

`Create` will build new Zend Lucene index for the first time and after creating the index if you need to reopen existing index to manipulate data into it, use `open`. [Refer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.index-creation.html)

I have used following code in my implementation and it works fine:
It will first tries to open an index, if index will not be available then it will create a new index.

```
try {
    $index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open("indexName");
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create("indexName");
}
```

Regarding field types refer [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html#zend.search.lucene.index-creation.understanding-field-types)

And yes, there is a limit to store data into an index. For **32 bit** platforms it is **2 GB**. Use 64-bit platforms for larger indices. [Source](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.index-creation.html#zend.search.lucene.index-creation.limitations)